# Add a Column to a Table that marks every entry with a specific ID as another value - SQL/BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is my first post here so I hope I am providing enough info to be clear in my question.

I have a SQL/BigQuery table that can be simplified to the following:

| Sale ID | Item | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2540 | 111 | Apple |
| 2540 | 112 | Lettuce |
| 2541 | 113 | Bread |

And essentially what I am trying to achieve is create a new column where whenever a Sale ID has a given Item, a marker will be placed on all rows that share that Sale ID. So, using Item 111 as an example, since Apple is a fruit, the top two rows would contain the Marker "Contains Fruit in Sale" and the new table would look like this:

| Sale ID | Item | Description | Marker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2540 | 111 | Apple | Contains Fruit in Sale |
| 2540 | 112 | Lettuce | Contains Fruit in Sale |
| 2541 | 113 | Bread |  |

Hopefully this makes sense. I have no idea how to go about doing this. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is the source of `Bread` in the output table?

Comment: The row with Bread would have no value in the Marker column, as that Sale ID (2541) does not have another row in the table with Item 111

Comment: I just realized the descriptions were different across tables. Apologies! Just edited and fixed it.

Comment: how you know what is fruit and what is not? do you have any extra lookup data/table for this?

Comment: I would imagine I would specify it in the WHERE section of the SQL, based on the item number or even the description. Another option probably would be to do it as a case when in the select section? But then I don't know how I'd get lines not tied Lettuce to contain the appropriate marker.

I could also use an extra lookup data/table but don't know how to add it to a BigQuery SQL if that data/table is not part of the Google Cloud.

Comment: Hello @SilverSkier. If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: @VishalK thank you so much!I found a way to integrate your query into my existing query using WITH AS and got the result I was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the below query for your requirement:

```
SELECT
 A.SaleID,
 A.ItemID,
 A.Description,
 B.Marker
FROM
 `project.dataset.table` A
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT
   SaleID,
   Marker
 FROM (
   SELECT
     SaleID,
     CASE
       WHEN Description IN ('Apple', 'Mango') THEN 'Contains Fruit in Sale'
   END
     AS Marker
   FROM
     `project.dataset.table`)
 WHERE
   Marker='Contains Fruit in Sale' ) B
ON
 A.SaleID =B.SaleID;
```

Actual Table:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!